# Print a 2-d array , Matrix style with the element indices

Tags: python

I am trying to print:

```
a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]
a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2]
a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]
```

My attempt:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print("a[{}][{}]\t".format(i,j),end="")
    print("")
    print("a[{}][{}]\t".format(i,j),end="")
```

but I am getting the following output:

```
a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]
a[0][2] a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2]
a[1][2] a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]
a[2][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print("a[{}][{}]\t".format(i,j),end="")
    print("")
```

which result in:

```
a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2] 
a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2] 
a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using f-strings, you can do:

```
n = 3
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(f'a[{i}][{j}]', end='\t')
    print()

# a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]
# a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2]                                           
# a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]
```